# Create a new column based on the values of other one

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have the file data.csv with information about the customer experience in one shop and the total spent in the shop.
Each customer gives points depending on their customer experience so the dataset looks like this:

```
Ranking     Total Spent 
9.5         1245
5           500.58
7.8         1000.69
3           200
6.2         412.45
```

I would like to create a new column called "experience" where its values depend on the "ranking" column. For example:

```
ranking >= 8 the new column value will be the string "Very satisfied" 
ranking >= 6 && ranking < 8 the new column value will be "Satisfied"
ranking >= 5 && ranking < 6 the new column value will be "Neutral"
ranking >= 3 && ranking < 5 the new column value will be "Bad"
ranking >= 0 && ranking < 3 the new column value will be "Horrible"
```

So the desired output is:

```
Ranking     Total Spent      Experience
9.5         1245             Very satisfied
5           500.58           Neutral
7.8         1000.69          Satisfied
3           200              Bad
6.2         412.45           Satisfied
```

I tried with the following code but is not working:

```
awk -F,'NR==1{$3="Experience";print;next} 
$1>=8 {print $0, "Very satisfied";next}
$1>=6 && $1<8 {print $0, "Satisfied";next}
$1>=5 && $1<6 {print $0, "Neutral";next}
$1>=3 && $1<5 {print $0, "Bad";next}
$1>=0 && $1<3 {print $0, "Horrible";next}' data.csv
```

Comment: Your example input does not match the `awk` script. There is no field 17. What exactly means "is not working"? Do you get an error? Different output? Please [edit] your question to create a [mre]. Your script does not implement the specified `>=` condition. It should probably be `$17>=6 && $17<8` etc. For your example input you need `$1` and `$2` instead of `$17` and `$18`.

Comment: Is there any double-quote in `data.csv`? check the output of `grep \" data.csv`

Comment: There is not any double-quote

Comment: @ed14 You still did not explain what you mean with "is not working". With the script in the question you will get an error message because of the missing space between `-F,` and `'NR==1...`? You don't need to specify an input field separator using the `-F` option if the field separator does not occur in the input.

Comment: I have the code in a file called test.awk so when I use gawk -f test.awk data.csv there is no response

Comment: The code in your question (`awk -F,'NR==1...`)  is a shell script with the shell calling awk so if you're saving that in a file and trying to interpret it with awk then that'll fail plus you have a syntax error in the way it does so (no space before the first `'`) so there's a couple of reasons why `gawk -f test.awk data.csv` would fail for you to start working on.

Comment: And another 1 - your awk script is using `,` as the FS but your sample input doesn't contain any commas, it's not a CSV but you're trying to treat it as if it were.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are really close. Just `OFS` missing. To avoid having to escape quotes you can create a script like this

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
NR==1 {FS=","; OFS="\t"; $2="Experience";print;next}
$1>=8 {print $0, "Very satisfied";next}
$1>=6 && $1<8 {print $0, "Satisfied";next}
$1>=5 && $1<6 {print $0, "Neutral";next}
$1>=3 && $1<5 {print $0, "Bad";next}
$1>=0 && $1<3 {print $0, "Horrible";next}
```

give permission

```
chmod +x myscript
```

and run it

```
./myscript data.csv
```

Comment: You (and OP) could drop off those latter comparisons due to the high-to-low comparison  order, ie. `$1>=6 && $1<8` to just  `$1>=6` etc,

Comment: @JamesBrown definitely

Comment: Thank you, now is working flawless :), I only have to point out that I am using OFS="," instead of OFS="/t". My data is in CSV

Comment: @ed14 If you use `OFS=","` your output should have fields separated with `,`. This does not match the expected output shown in the question.